# Create an empty json field using JAVA

Tags: java, json

I want to generate a JSON like this:

```
{ “index”:{} }
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
JSONObject indexObject = new JSONObject( );
indexObject.put( "index", new JSONArray());
```

but it outputs this:

```
{"index":[]}
```

Comment: Try `indexObject.put( "index", new JSONObject());`

Answer (score 3):

That happens, because you are putting `JSONArray()` there. Try putting `JSONObject()` just like that:

```
indexObject.put( "index", new JSONObject());
```

Thanks, @bhusak.

Comment: why would you duplicate the answer that OP has given?

Comment: Because it was not given as an answer